# Algorithm to track the price of a particular item every 5 minutes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, algorithm, database-design

I have a PHP script that fetches the price of a particular item from an API. The script is executed by a cron job that runs every 5 minutes. The price of the item remains same most of the time, and changes only about 4 or 5 times a day.

This is how I have the table structured as of now:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_details` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end` datetime NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=38 ;
```

In the front-end, I'd like to display the prices during various periods. So if the price changed 3 times during the day, there would be 3 time ranges, and the corresponding prices.

Example:

```
2015-05-31 01:55:00 PM to 2015-05-31 04:25:00 PM
  Price = $22.33

2015-05-31 04:25:00 PM to 2015-05-31 08:25:00 PM
  Price = $33.54

2015-05-31 08:25:00 PM to 2015-05-31 10:25:00 PM
  Price = $37.37
```

If I were to insert a new record for every time the script gets executed, there would be 200+ records in a single day, and it'd get messy very quickly. So I execute the INSERT query only if the fetched price is different from the previous one.

This is how my script is now:

```
$last_row = get_last_low();
$current_price = get_current_price();

if ($last_row['price'] == $current_price) 
{
    UPDATE product_details SET `end`=%s ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
}
else 
{
    INSERT INTO product_details (`start`, `end`, `price`) 
    VALUES (NOW(), NOW(), $current_price)
}

foreach (get_all_records() as $item) 
{
    display();
}
```

If the user specifies, I'd like to display the increase/decrease in price next to each entry. Should I perhaps add another `value_increased` field in the table? I'm totally clueless as to how to structure the table correctly, in the best way possible, so I don't have to look back later on.

How would  you change it? (I just posted my approach to show what I've tried so far; your answer doesn't necessarily have to stick to it. I'm open to ANY ideas, as long as it's better than my hack.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have the previous and new prices when you do your INSERT, you can easily calculate the value_increased and store it then itself. So basically yes, add another value_increased field in the table.

Instead of updating the 'end' every time you query the API, if you keep track of the last run time in your code, you could just update it once before your INSERT (have it NULL on the initial INSERT).

Something like

```
$last_row = get_last_low();
$current_price = get_current_price();

if ($last_row['price'] != $current_price) 
{
    UPDATE product_details SET `end`=%s WHERE 'end' IS NULL;

    INSERT INTO product_details (`start`, `end`, `price`) 
    VALUES (NOW(), null, $current_price)
}
```

Also, if you are displaying the CURRENT price of all items your query becomes much more simpler - something like

```
SELECT * FROM product_details WHERE 'end' IS NULL;
```

instead of something more complicated (with multiple products, you'd have to get the latest 'end' and then join again to get the corresponding price. Of course, if you are the only thing you are doing is showing all records, this wouldn't be too much of a factor.

The single UPDATE means that you'd also just hit the DB far fewer times (i.e. as many times as there is a price change, instead of as many times as you hit the API)

**Cons**

The downside is that if your application crashes, you won't know WHEN you last got the price (if tracking each and every price is mandatory, you'd basically have to query the database on the API side for all time after your last PRICE was changed. For example

```
1.00 PM    $1.1
1.15 PM    $2.0
1.30 PM    $2.0
1.45 PM    $2.0
--- application crash ----
```

With your current program your DB would have

```
1.00 PM     $1.1
1.45 PM     $2.0
```

So, for error recovery, you'd basically query the API for all price changes after 1.45 PM. With the modified program your DB would have

```
1.00 PM     $1.1
NULL        $2.0
```

So, for error recovery, you'd have to query the API for all price changes after 1.00 PM. Note that in both cases, the number of records returned by the API would be same, it's just that the API's rerun has a SLIGHTLY (depends on when the last price change was) larger dataset to filter out.

Comment: Could you explain the second paragraph? I'm not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: If you give `end` an initial value of null instead of the current date and time, you have much less work to do.  First, you can select just the rows with null values and you don't need to worry about the last row.  Also, when displaying, you only select records with null in the `end` field.  This also makes the extra field unnecessary.

Comment: @Joseph John - Dan Bracuk's explanation is correct. Thanks Dan Bracuk!

Comment: Do you think you could edit the answer to show the pseudo-code?

Comment: Thank you for the help, by the way. I really appreciate it!